# Does monotone convergence theorem gives uniform convergence?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, random-variables

> *Monotone convergence theorem*
>
> If $X_n$ are positive random variables and increasing to $X$, then $$\lim_{n \to
>  \infty} E[X_n] = E[X]$$

My problem, though, is that $X$ depends on $m$, so it really is $X_m$ and $X_n$ are a sequence of positive r.v. that increase to $X_m$. 
Therefore those mean values are really function of $m$.

I am trying to apply the following theorem (can't find its name.. I think it's some kind of application of lebesgue dominated converge theorem but I am not really an expert on this topic)

> If $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = f$ uniformily and $\lim_{t \to t_0} f_n
>  (t) = l_n$, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{t \to t_0} f_n(t) =
>  \lim_{t \to t_0} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(t)$$

My question is: does the monotone convergence theorem guarantees that $E[X_n] \to E[X]$ uniformily, so that i can apply the above theorem? If not, what are the minimum hypothesis I have to make on $X$?

(To give some background, I have a sequence of positive  random variables $X_m$ and , for every fixed $m$, I take a sequence of positive *simple* random variables $X_{n,m}$ that increase to $X_m$)